# Python: how to checking if we are currently writing to the pipe?

Tags: python, input, subprocess, output

```
import os
import fcntl
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
def setNonBlocking(fd):
    """
    Set the file description of the given file descriptor to non-blocking.
    """
    flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    flags = flags | os.O_NONBLOCK
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, flags)

p = Popen("./a.out", stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, bufsize = 1)
setNonBlocking(p.stdout)
setNonBlocking(p.stderr)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(.1)     //wait for writing complete                    
        out1 = p.stdout.read()
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        print out1
        if p.poll() == 0:
            break
    line = raw_input()
    p.stdin.write(line)
    p.stdin.write('\n')
    p.stdin.flush()
```

Interactive input/output using python. 
a.out is a small C++ program that input a, b, and output a + b. It is OK with the code. But I think if a.out is a big program and need more than 0.1s to exec. I should change the line below.

```
time.sleep(.1)
```

I want to checking if we are currently writing to the pipe. So I can do it like below.

```
while pipe is writing:
    continue;
```

I am new hand in Python. I have google for it all day and fail to solve it. Who can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: your code writes to the pipe using `p.stdin` object. Those 3 lines is the only place in your code that writes to the pipe. Nothing writes to the pipe if the lines are not executed (as far as I can tell the `p.stdin` calls are blocking).

Comment: But the program a.out will writes to the pipe when it executed.

Comment: Then your question should be: "how do I know when to **read** from the pipe?" You/we (the code in the *parent* that is under your/our control) **read** from the pipe; the *child* process (that you can't change otherwise you should use a more sensible protocol to exchange data) writes to the pipe.

Comment: Oh, yes. I am sorry I didn't make myself clear. I use the command `strace` to do it. I don't know if it is a good method.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set `p.stdout` to non-blocking. That way `p.stdout.read()` will automatically cause your program to wait until the output of the subprocess is ready.

Comment: Yes, but if we in input mode， it will hang. So I should  judge if it is in input mode. But I also can't find some solution.

Comment: Then maybe you need to write to `p.stdin` first, and then read from `p.stdout`.

Comment: But I actually don't know what a.out is, I use the shell command `strace` to judge if the program is wait for reading now. I don't know if there are some ways to solved in Python.